# CodeMirror: simulated cursors and selections for collaborative editing

Tags: javascript, html, css, editor, codemirror

I'm looking to make a collaborative text/code editor with [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/), using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

So, as well as the local cursor (not pointer) and selection, I need to insert a simulated cursor(s) and selection(s) representing the remote user's cursor(s) and selection(s).

The simulated cursor(s) and selection(s) should not affect text editing in any way (for example, the simulated selection(s) should not be replaced by text which the local user types).

Also, simulated cursor(s) and simulator(s) should have a different colour(s).

So, what method would I use to go about doing this? Are there built in functions in CodeMirror, or will I need to superimpose my own elements on top of the CodeMirror editor?

In summary, I need:

- Simulated ("pseudo") cursor(s)
- Simulated ("pseudo") selection(s)
- Different colours

Thank you so much!

Comment: You can look at source code of Firepad collaboration editor for CodeMirror - https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firepad, somehow they implement colored remote selections and remote cursors. The remote cursor is implemented as an widget, but I do not know the details.